# DNS result very weird

Tags: networking, dns, osx-yosemite, ping, dig

> $ nslookup reddit.com
>       Server:     8.8.8.8
>       Address:    8.8.8.8#53
>
> ```
> Non-authoritative answer:
> Name:   reddit.com
> Address: 0.0.44.193
>
>
>
> $ while true; do nslookup reddit.com; done
> Server:     8.8.8.8
> Address:    8.8.8.8#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
> Name:   reddit.com
> Address: 0.0.45.62
>
> Server:     8.8.8.8
> Address:    8.8.8.8#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
> Name:   reddit.com
> Address: 0.0.45.63
>
> Server:     8.8.8.8
> Address:    8.8.8.8#53
>
> Non-authoritative answer:
> Name:   reddit.com
> Address: 0.0.45.64
>
> ^C
> ```

Obviously, the result is 0.0.xx.xx, and xx is increment. weird! But ping worked.

> ```
> $ ping baidu.com
> PING baidu.com (0.0.46.103): 56 data bytes
> 64 bytes from 123.125.114.144: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=76.006 ms
> 64 bytes from 123.125.114.144: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=3.757 ms
> ^C
> --- baidu.com ping statistics ---
> 2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
> round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 3.757/39.882/76.006/36.124 ms
> ```

Dig result weird too.

> ```
> $ dig reddit.com @8.8.8.8
>
> ; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> reddit.com @8.8.8.8
> ;; global options: +cmd
> ;; Got answer:
> ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 26859
> ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
>
> ;; QUESTION SECTION:
> ;reddit.com.            IN  A
>
> ;; ANSWER SECTION:
> reddit.com.     1   IN  A   0.0.46.104
>
> ;; Query time: 0 msec
> ;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
> ;; WHEN: Wed Jan 27 09:19:11 2016
> ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 44
> ```

**Any help is appreciated.**

What I did? list below:

> ```
> sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.mDNSResponder.plist
> sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
> ```

Never worked.

system:

> ```
> OS X El Capitan
> Version 10.11.2 (15C50)
> ```

Comment: What are you saying is weird? they look like perfectly normal DNS results

Answer (score 0):

After [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/42uxy7/dns_result_very_odd/) this question in reddit.com, [phaew](https://www.reddit.com/user/phaeew) mention local searchdomain, I check /etc/resolve.conf:

```
nameserver 192.168.11.1
```

It resolved.